# Passing credentials to downstream build step in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We're trying to start a downstream build which expects "UserName" and "UserPassword" as parameters.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(
        credentialsId: params.deployCredentialsId,
        usernameVariable: 'MY_USER',
        passwordVariable: 'MY_PASS',
)]) {

    build(job: "deploy/nightly",
        parameters: [stringParam(name: "UserName", value: MY_USER), password(name: "UserPassword", value: MY_PASS),
        ... more parameters
    )
}
```

but the downstream job never sees the UserName / UserPassword parameters. Is there a bug in the above definition, or should I look at the downstream job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look in the downstream job. It should have a 'parameters' block that looks like:

```
parameters {
    string(defaultValue: "", description: 'foo', name: "UserName")
    string(defaultValue: "", description: 'foo', name: "UserPassword")
}
```

Then in your stage you can do this:

```
stage('PrintParameter'){
    steps{
        sh 'echo ${UserName}'
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct, even though in my case the cause was something else. Apparently the (blackbox) downstream job had a check on an unrelated property, and the fact that I was passing it UPPERCASE resulted in a failing credentials check, and the job ultimately asking for a password. Goes to say ... sometimes the cause is quite unrelated to the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 2 Jenkins pipeline jobs called job-A and job-B and you want to call job-B from job-A by passing some parameters and you want to access those on job-B. The example would look like below:

job-A

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('Build Job-B') {
            steps {
                build(job: "job-B", parameters: [string(name:"username",value: "user"),password(name:"password",value: "fake")], propagate: false, wait: true, quietPeriod: 5)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

job-B

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('echo parameter') {
            steps {
                sh "echo $params"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note-

1. `params` is by default available in all pipeline job, no matter whether you use a scripted pipeline or a declarative pipeline.
2. you no need to define any parameter in the downstream job

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the issue is not generally with parameters, those work fine. The only thing not working is to pass on the credentials.

Comment: you mean with this - `parameters: [stringParam(name: "UserName", value: MY_USER), password(name: "UserPassword", value: MY_PASS)` , MY_USER and MY_PASS environment variable is not being passed ? 

If that the case , try to change from MY_USER to `"${env.MY_USER}"` and MY_PASS to `"${env.MY_PASS}"`.